# weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException:Timestampvalidation failed

Tags: java, soap, request, weblogic, soapui

I am trying to send a `SOAP request`. Getting following error:

> weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException:Timestampvalidation
>   failed. Error in the soap message request.

I tried various things but same request works on different server .

Comment: Please provide the code that prompted the error message

Comment: Do both servers use the same version of the webservice? Is it possible that schema validation has been disabled on the one that actually works? I've previously experienced people disabling it to gain a little performance boost.